# Managing Disposable classes Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, lifecycle

I'm wondering how to manage an object using DI.  Suppose I have a class

```
class Foo : IFoo, IDisposable
{
    // ...
}
```

Then this class is injected into another class

```
class Bar
{
    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        this.Foo = foo
    }

    IFoo Foo { get; set; }
 }
```

Then I bind this in some scope (my example uses MVC and Ninject)

```
this.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InRequestScope();
```

I'm wondering, since the Dependency Injection framework handles the lifecycle of `Foo`, should I implement IDispoable in `Bar`?  My thought is that DI is managing the lifecycle of `Foo`, so don't touch it, in case another class is using `Foo`.  Also, since the disposable object is passed into `Bar` as a constructor parameter, `Bar` doesn't **wrap** a disposable object, so it doesn't know how the caller of `Bar` wants to use `Foo` after `Bar` is garbage collected.  Is this right?

Comment: Nicholas Blumhardt has a great post on this subject, using Autofact as an example but applicable in general http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/

Comment: Looking at some MSDN articles, it seems Microsoft will do both:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at%28v=vs.110%29 (StremReader) "The StreamReader object calls Dispose() on the provided Stream object when StreamReader.Dispose is called"
but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw%28v=vs.110%29 
(Bitmap) "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your assumptions are correct. Ninject will dispose the object for you.

Comment: I realized this when testing.  I guess my main question is, who is responsible for disposing of an object.  My conclusion based on searching was that the object that created the disposable object is responsible for disposing it.  So, in this case Ninject.

Answer (score 4):

This is the general problem of managing lifetime. The basic rule is that he who creates an object has the ownership of that instance.  The owner should dispose/destroy that instance. Ownership can be passed on to someone else, which makes that 'someone else' responsible of destroying that instance.

In your case the Foo instance is not created by Bar, so bar is not responsible of disposing that instance. Since Ninject created that instance for you, it is responsible for its clean-up.

Ownership can be passed on, but this must be something explicit. A good example of explicit ownership passing is the Factory design pattern:

```
IFoo CreateNewFoo();
```

Although this method creates new `IFoo` instances, it is pretty clear that he passes the ownership back to the caller.

A good example of a BAD way of passing ownership is .NET's `StreamReader` class. It takes a disposable object in its constructor, but it takes ownership. Although the documentation states that the class disposes the given object, this behavior dazzles many developers, because it goes against the general rule of ownership. Microsoft finally fixed this in .NET 4.5 by adding a ctor overload that allows suppressing the disposal of the given stream.